# Compiling module on OpenWRT: make can't find build directory

Tags: kernel-modules, c, openwrt

My setup:

- OpenWRT 18.06.1
- Raspberry Pi 2 B
- Kernel 4.9.120

Attempting to build a very simple [hello world kernel module](https://askubuntu.com/q/1083091/295286) results in the following error:

```
# make
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.120/build M=/c_programming/hellomodule modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.120/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Makefile isn't a problem, since it works on Ubuntu just fine. What I've done so far:

- I've checked and the directory indeed is missing.
- Checked with `opkg find '*headers*'` however there's no packages `linux-headers-<release>` like on Ubuntu.

How should I proceed to actually build this thing ?

Comment: On 2018, I wrote quite a detailed post titled ["Building custom OpenWRT packages: an (hopefully complete) guide"](https://dvblog.soabit.com/building-custom-openwrt-packages-an-hopefully-complete-guide/). It summarize the usage of the official OpenWRT SDK both to build "simple" sources as well as complete OpenWRT pagkages.

Should you be still in search for help... would you mind getting it a quick look?

If it will be helpful, I'll add this comment as a real answer.